# Define Permissions To The Schema In Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have defined a **testuser** in Master. I have a db with 2 schemas like: *dbo.Table* and *Test.Table*. So here we have 2 schemas with name: **dbo** and **Test**. How can I define the permission to my **testuser** to access only schema **Test**.

I have google and found the below lines useful:

**DENY SELECT ON schema::[dbo] TO [testuser]**

But when I run the above query the below error comes:

**Cannot find the user 'testuser', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

I am able to login with my new user(**testuser**).

Please help

Comment: I assume you're using sql server authentication. You'll have to create the testuser in the same schema.

Comment: Sorry I didn't got you. Can you please explain

Comment: In SQL Server, there are usually 2 security tabs. One at the database schema level and one at the server level. Where did you create the test user?

Comment: Which user do you use to excecute this query: `DENY SELECT ON schema::[dbo] TO [testuser]`

Comment: I have created in the master db

Comment: @MikkaRin: I am using sa user

Comment: Could ou attach content of `Security` branch from SQL Server Management Studio to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have created the testuser login, now you have to create an user in the database to be able to set database permissions to him.

```
USE myDatabase;
GO
CREATE USER testuser FOR LOGIN testuser;
GO
DENY SELECT ON schema::[dbo] TO [testuser]
GO
```

Comment: I have used the above query and run the query from my admin user(sa). But still I am able to see both schemas

Comment: What's the result of this?  `execute as user='testuser'; select has_perms_by_name('dbo', 'SCHEMA', 'SELECT'); REVERT;` -- does it returns 0 or 1?

Comment: Great, it means that the testuser user doesn't have the select permissions on dbo schema. That's what you wanted.

Comment: So how I will provide the select permission

Comment: I don't understand. You have succesfully denied select on dbo to testuser, wasn't it what you wanted to do?

Comment: Actually when I expand my Tables I only want to see only those schemas starts with "Client" not with "dbo".

Comment: Users can't see metadata on objects that they cannot access, so this should be OK.

Comment: But I am able to see all the objects of schema dbo. Can you please clearify me what "DENY SELECT" actually do. If  it restricts the user to access that schema or what??

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in my SQL Server.

**First: Create a Login in the Security Tab. You can also script it using this.**

```
/* For security reasons the login is created disabled and with a random password. */
/****** Object:  Login [TestUserLogon]    Script Date: 04/09/2014 08:33:06 ******/
CREATE LOGIN [TestUserLogon] WITH PASSWORD=N'stackoverflow', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
```

**Next: Create a user in the database and map that user to this login you've created.**

```
USE [abs2]
GO
CREATE USER [TestUser] FOR LOGIN [TestUserLogon]
GO
USE [abs2]
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[db_datareader] TO [TestUser]
GO
```

**Next: Grant or REVOKE privileges to the user from your sa login.**

```
GRANT SELECT ON DBO.aPPOINTMENTS TO tESTUSER
GO
```

When you login to sqlserver database, you'll have to use the LOGIN and not the USER.

Comment: Users can't see metadata on objects that they cannot access, so this should be OK.